# Firebase Firestore Query get One result

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for the best way to:
1. query for one single result, or
2. extract the first result from the query

tried: `collection[0]` and `collection.pop()` or `collection.shift()` and nothing works

I really don't like the code i'm using, but it works...

```
export const findUserByEmail = email => {
  return firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', email.toLowerCase())
    .get()
    .then(collection => {
      console.log(collection)
      let user
      collection.forEach(doc => user = doc.data())
      return user
    })
}
```

Comment: Your text says `result` but your code says `collection`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: thank you, yes it's a typo. editing now

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your query returns a `QuerySnapshot` ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot)). You can access the docs as an array via the `docs` property; each doc has a `data()` method:

```
export const findUserByEmail = email => {
  return firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('email', '==', email.toLowerCase())
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if(!querySnapshot.empty) {
        const user = querySnapshot.docs[0].data()
        // rest of your code 
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: solution would be .then(snap => snap.docs[0].data())  thank you

Comment: is "querySnapshot.docs[0]" standard of Google to fetch first document? If yes, then it's really really bad programming. I am not blaming to you "Charles-allen". There should be inbuilt function like to fetch list of documennts use ".get()" and to fetch only first document use ".first()". I am not aware that Google has ".first()" or any similar function. Its just basic thing, I think every framework / CMS has such feature. eg. Laravel / Lumen has "get()" and "first()" functions for the same. We are hacking code to fetch first document by "querySnapshot.docs[0].data()".

Comment: "if(!querySnapshot.empty) {" did not work for me because there is no "empty" function so I have checked documents length. Please see the code: 

if(querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
          _mappedUserInfo  = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
        }

Comment: @kamlesh - Your error message suggests you called it like `querySnapshot.empty()` (incorrect). It's a property not a method. Use it like: `querySnapshot.empty`. See [the docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty). If you prefer `docs.length`, that's fine; just longer.

Answer (score 1):

**Firestore with Flutter solution:**

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: loggedInUserId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      List listData = querySnapshot.docs.toList().map((item) {
        // to fetch list of all documents information
        return item.data();
      }).toList();

      if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
        // to fetch first document information
        _mappedUserInfo = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
      }

      print("listData: ${listData.toString()}");
      print("_mappedUserInfo: ${_mappedUserInfo.toString()}");
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('data error: $e');
    });
```

**Result:**

**Fetched List of documents:**

```
listData: [{name: null, addedOn: Timestamp(seconds=1623663004, nanoseconds=581000000), email: john.doe2021@mailinator.com, phoneNumber: null, userId: yRARGJOaAbM78MW5OBlVEB3VyKkr, lastSignInOn: Timestamp(seconds=1623663004, nanoseconds=581000000), photoURL: null}]
```

**Fetched single document:**

```
_mappedUserInfo: {name: null, addedOn: Timestamp(seconds=1623663004, nanoseconds=581000000), email: john.doe2021@mailinator.com, phoneNumber: null, userId: yRARGJOaAbM78MW5OBlVEB3VyKkr, lastSignInOn: Timestamp(seconds=1623663004, nanoseconds=581000000), photoURL: null}
```

It worked for me. I hope, this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

> tried: `collection[0]` and `collection.pop()` and nothing works

Those 2 in order means:

1. `collection[0]` - *access the first element of an array*
2. `collection.pop()` - *pop get's rid of the last*
   element of an array

Maybe based on your code logic, you should try: `collection[0].data()`; as by using `collection[0]` you access the first element, but from your existing code you need to call `.data()` to extract it.

`forEach` does simply access to the whole content of `collection`.
Whilst `collection.pop()` is just not the proper tool for the job in this case.

Comment: collection is not an array, it's a firebase object, with it's own properties. the fact that it has a forEach is a coincidence... so collection[0] doesn't get me anything. collection.pop doesn't exist, same as .shift.  I know what pop means, it's just i am sure that if there are results, it will be always one, so it wouldn't matter